# TensorFlow 2.3.0 in Spyder (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, python-3.7, spyder

I'm quite new to programming. I have Tensorflow 2.3.0 installed in Anaconda on my PC, I confirmed this in the Anaconda prompt. I however can't train my model importing Keras in Spyder; it keeps returning "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher." Any help??

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and Spyder may use different Python.

Comment: Environment problem. Make sure spyder is using same environment as where you installed Tensorflow 2.3.0

Comment: Many thanks guys, however as I earlier stated, I'm new to Programing. How do I get around assessing the environments/ pythons versions? And if the problem is found to be a differential in the same, how do I correct it?